# Common Lisp: how to access a row of a certain multi-dimension array?

Tags: common-lisp

Let's say I wrote

```
(setf s (make-array (list 9 9) :element-type 'bit))
```

so s is a 9x9 matrix of bits.

and I want to get the 1st row of s. How do I get that?

I could have done the following:

```
(setf s (make-array 9 
          :element-type 'array 
          :initial-element 
          (make-array 9 :element-type 'bit)))
```

and access the first row by (svref s 0). 

But I want to know if there is a built-in way. 

(And the 2 dim array seems to allocate less bytes).

Comment: You might be interested in http://tkpapp.blogspot.in/2010/05/sub-array-indexing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defun array-slice (arr row)
    (make-array (array-dimension arr 1) 
      :displaced-to arr 
       :displaced-index-offset (* row (array-dimension arr 1))))
```

This only works for row slices and doesn't, IIRC, copy the array. Writing to the slice will modify the original array.

Comment: So there is no built-in function for this? Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, but displaced arrays let you hack up this sort of thing. There's probably a `row-major-aref` in the internals of the displacement code.

Comment: https://github.com/tpapp/cl-slice extends this functionality substantially.